# How can you add text to a PowerShell table result?

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

I'm trying to figure out how I can add some text such as MHz or GB to the results in the PowerShell table. Is it possible with a `foreach` loop?

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMmory |
    Format-Table Banklabel, Manufacturer,
        @{Label="Speed"; Expression={$_.ConfiguredClockSpeed}},
        @{Label="Capacity"; Expression={[int64]($_.Capacity/1GB)}} -AutoSize
```

[image: Result 1]

I have another way that comes close, but will not work with multiple results as it doesnt add the informtion into new rows.

```
$Disk = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk
$DiskSpace = [int64]($Disk.Size/1GB)
$FreeSpace = [INT64]($Disk.FreeSpace/1GB)
$UsedSpace = (($DiskSpace-$FreeSpace)/$DiskSpace).ToString("P0")
$OBJ = New-Object PSObject
$OBJ | Add-Member NoteProperty "ID" ($Disk.DeviceID)
$OBJ | Add-Member NoteProperty "Name" ($Disk.VolumeName)
$OBJ | Add-Member NoteProperty "Format" ($Disk.FileSystem)
$OBJ | Add-Member NoteProperty "Capacity" ("$DiskSpace-GB")
$OBJ | Add-Member NoteProperty "Free Space" ("$FreeSpace-GB")
$OBJ | Add-Member NoteProperty "Used" ($UsedSpace)
Write-Output $OBJ | Format-Table
```

[image: Result 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the concatenation for your requirement.

replace

```
Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmemory | Format-Table Banklabel, Manufacturer, @{Label="Speed";` Expression={$_.ConfiguredClockSpeed}}, @{Label="Capacity";` Expression={[INT64]($_.Capacity/1GB)}} -autosize
```

with this:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmemory | Format-Table Banklabel, Manufacturer, @{Label="Speed";` Expression={"$($_.ConfiguredClockSpeed) MHz"}}, @{Label="Capacity";` Expression={"$([INT64]($_.Capacity/1GB)) GB"}} -autosize
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use much more complex expression, see following example:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmemory | Format-Table Banklabel, Manufacturer, @{Label="Speed";`
  Expression={$_.ConfiguredClockSpeed}}, @{Label="Capacity";`
  Expression={([INT64]($_.Capacity/1GB)).ToString()+" GB"}} -autosize
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're already using calculated properties it's easy to extend them. It depends what you try to achieve. I would recommend to place the unit into table header like this:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmemory | 
    Select-Object -Property Banklabel, Manufacturer, @{Name='Speed in MHz';Expression={$_.ConfiguredClockSpeed}}, @{Name='Capacity in GB'; Expression={[INT64]($_.Capacity/1GB)}}
```

If you really need it in the table you could do it like this:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmemory | 
    Select-Object -Property Banklabel, Manufacturer, @{Name='Speed';Expression={"{0} MHz" -f $_.ConfiguredClockSpeed}}, @{Name='Capacity in GB'; Expression={"{0} GB" -f [INT64]($_.Capacity/1GB)}}
```

But this way you loose the possibility to calculate with your results. It's just strings now.

Comment: He is more looking it in the results and not in column names.

Comment: That's why I posted both.  ;-)